# 15 Tiles Sliding Block

Tags: sliding-blocks

Solve the sliding puzzle by moving the tiles to the space available until the right image is revealed. You cannot move them because it is just a picture, so just cut each piece and jig-saw solve it with paint.

[image]

What animal can you think of?

Comment: not necessarily alive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @IAmInPLS made clear the letter is

> the leter C

This letter reminded me of one logo

> Kentucky Fried Chicken[image: KFC Logo]

Thus the animal is

> A chicken, dead or alive as hinted by the OP

Comment: Nice - that has to be it

Answer (score 5):

Long shot answer:

> Rhinoceros

As @IAmInPLS mentioned, we see:

> A huge C and a registered trademark logo.

What I was thinking it's just a rebus:

> R in O --> Rino --> Rhino
>  Rhino C --> Rhinoceros.

Besides:

> The picture is in red, because the rhinoceros is currently on the [red list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUCN_Red_List) of IUCN.

Comment: I like the answer, but I can't see how C is "Ceros". (Too bad that [Red Sea Rhino](https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/saltwater-red-sea-rhino/308706/) is a beer and not an animal.)

Answer (score 2):

By sliding the pieces, you obtain (approximatively):

> [image]

which (I can be utterly wrong) makes me think to:

> The [Cornell Big Red](http://images.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2F3%2F3d%2FCornellBigRed.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCornell_Big_Red&h=240&w=229&tbnid=beLRDZQ9NaccdM%3A&vet=1&docid=rNdzOy1ssApDiM&ei=fPNTWLPiJ4T_ab3qlKAF&tbm=isch&client=firefox-b-ab&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=847&page=0&start=0&ndsp=31&ved=0ahUKEwizkMPw7_jQAhWEfxoKHT01BVQQMwgcKAAwAA&safe=off&bih=732&biw=1504):
>
>   [image]
>
> so the animal is a **bear**.

Comment: The C could also be a horseshoe, perhaps? It doesn't seem like that logo actually exists.